# Column checkboxes, checking/unchecking by columns

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function marcarJob(source) 
    {
        checkboxes=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for(i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++)
        {
            if(checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox") 
            {
                checkboxes[i].checked=source.checked;
            }
        }
    }

    function marcarDeproc(source) 
    {
        checkboxes=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for(i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++) //record all controls
        {
            if(checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox") 
            {
                checkboxes[i].checked=source.checked;
            }
        }
    }

    function marcarEs(source) 
    {
        checkboxes=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for(i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++)
        {
            if(checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox") 
            {
                checkboxes[i].checked=source.checked; // (mark/unmark all)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The way it is, when i check one of the top checkboxes checks ALL checkboxses.

I need they to light up in columns. If the first is checked, the other ones must also be checked/uncheck, ordered in columns, the first check box of a column is like a "SELECT ALL" but only for the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to note is that you are accessing checkbox with tagName, it would find all the checkboxes on the page.

You need to create checkboxes of single column with same name as following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="column1_checkAll" onclick="javascript: checkUncheckAll('column1', this);"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="column1_checkbox" id="chk1" /> 
to 
<input type="checkbox" name="column1_checkbox" id="chkn" />
```

And add the following javascript to check/uncheck all checkboxes of single column.

```
function checkUncheckAll(columnNo, checkboxObject){
    if(checkboxObject){ // Check for null IE
        var checkStatus = checkboxObject.checked; // CheckAll checked or unchecked status
        var columnName = columnNo+'_checkbox';
        var allCheckboxes = document.getElementsByName(columnName);             

        for(var i= 0; i < allCheckbox.length; i++){
            allCheckboxes[i].checked = status;
        }
    }
}
```